# Django - Export search results to PDF / CSV

Tags: python, django, csv, pdf

In my web application, I've created a basic search that allows a user to query records based on a couple of fields (date, created by, etc.). I want the user to be able to export those specific search results to PDF/CSV, but I'm having difficulty understanding how this might be done.

I've already built a search and a results page that work. On the results page, there are two different hyperlinks/buttons (not sure which I should be using yet) that read "Export to PDF" and "Export to CSV". When the user clicks on a link/button, it should export the results from the search. I am familiar with ReportLab and the Django docs on exporting to PDF. My question is specifically about how I should handle the search results so that I can export them if the user decides to do so.

**What is the best approach to this problem?**

- Do I save the search results into a session variable as a pickle object ([Example Pt.1](http://amgcomputing.blogspot.ca/2014/09/add-button-to-export-search-results-in.html), [Example Pt.2](http://amgcomputing.blogspot.com/2015/07/add-button-to-export-search-results-in_13.html)) and then load it when the user wants to export to PDF/CSV?
- Should I save the raw SQL of the user's search to a database and then look it up and re-execute the query when the user wants to export to PDF/CSV?
- Should I simply pass the search variables to hidden fields in a form on the results page and then when "Export to PDF" is clicked, re-execute the search?

Is there a generally accepted way of doing this kind of thing? I see it often and want to implement the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are not very expensive and your data isn't supposed to change in the period between the user saw your page and clicked an "Export" button, you don't need to save your queries and results to a separate model. You just re-run the query and feed it to your user not in the HTML, but in some other format.

CSV: The view code that generates your context remains pretty the same, you just change the output template. For example, you could mimic the [Django Rest Framework's behaviour](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/format-suffixes/), making your urls look like:

- `/a/path?with=query`
- `/a/path.csv?with=query`
- `/a/path.pdf?with=query`

and choosing the approrpiate template based on the path.

As for PDF, things get a bit more complicated, take a look at [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf/) .

Answer (score 0):

I think based on your query, the best way of doing it is make the query once! it is optimized, although you should not save the search results to a database, it is only an unnecessary load.

The way I think you should do:

1. Search the pdf making packages available:

   1.1 [The reportlab](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-pdf/) : it is the default package suggested in django docs, but as far as I know there will be some problems
   outputing unicode characters in PDF

   1.2 [WKHTMLTOPDF](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf) : the one I like the most! it uses a binary file to execute the pdf making command, it is easy to use and convert your HTML
   file to a nice PDF. currently I'm using it, but you will have some
   problems with executing binary file on production server.
   1.3 [Python PDF Kit](https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/) : just another pdf kit.
2. Search the csv file making packages available:

   2.1 you can use [django csv](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-csv/) : it is easy to use, you won't have problems creating csv file.
3. write some templates like this with GET method :

   ```
   def myview(request):

       type = request.GET.get('type', 'html')

       # do processing
       if type == 'html':
           # return html
       else if type == 'csv':
           # return csv
       else if type == 'PDF':
           # return PDF
   ```

When the url `http://yourserver/myview` is accessed it will return the html part of the view that is your search results.
If you access a url like `http://yourserver/myview?type=csv` it will render the csv part of the view. and `http://yourserver/myview?type=pdf` for your pdf view.